# Raw socket returning unknown bytes /x03/x0043/x13/

Tags: python, firefox, encoding, decoding

I am using python raw sockets to receive data from my browser when i go to the IP on Firefox.

Here is the code:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 80))
while True:
    while runFlag:
        print('running')
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(65565)
        #data.decode('UTF-8')
        print(data)
```

Returns:

```
b'E\x00\x01H\x1e\x08\x00\x00\x80\x11Y\xf0\xc0\xa8\x01\x05\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00D\x
00C\x014\x90\xfe\x01\x01\x06\x00B\x19\x8c\xd4\x00\x00\x80\x00\xc0\xa8\x01\x05'...
shortened version of output
```

I was wondering if anyone could please explain this output to me as I am not sure what it means.

Comment: Shouldn't a client side socket use `connect` instead of `bind?`

Comment: I'm not sure, i thought that a client used `connect` and a server used `bind` because it is listening for packets and not connecting to a server. in this case i am hosting a basic raw socket to listen for packets that my browser sends when it attempts to connect to the raw socket server.